# Load all ResourceBundles and pick correct resource based on key and Locale

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Okay, so I have been given this challenge to implement a "Service" that loads in all the resources for all locales that we support. Then it should be possible to pick they resource from correct ResourceBundle based on the key and the current Locale. How can I achieve this?

So this is how I have made my solution, I have a `Service` called `TranslationService`

```
public class TranslationService {

    private List<ResourceBundle> resourceBundles;

    public TranslationService(final Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle messageTexts = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageTexts", locale, new Utf8Control());
        ResourceBundle notificationTexts = ResourceBundle.getBundle("NotificationTexts", locale, new Utf8Control());
        ResourceBundle generalTexts = ResourceBundle.getBundle("GeneralTexts", locale, new Utf8Control());
        Collections.addAll(this.resourceBundles, messageTexts, notificationTexts, generalTexts);
    }

    public String getText(String key) {
        String text = null;

        for (ResourceBundle resourceBundle : resourceBundles) {
            try {
                text = resourceBundle.getString(key);
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
                // DO NOTHING: If the key is not found in first resource means not that it isn't in the next
                // check all resources for the key.
            }
        }

        if (text == null) {
            log.error("Could not find key {} in any resource.", key);
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

So what I want to achieve is to be able to load in all the specified `Bundles` for all supported `Locales` so to say I want to load in on initialization ex the `MessageTexts_en_GB.properties`, `MessageTexts_fr_FR.properties`, `MessageTexts_ja_JP.properties` etc. And then based on what locale is used and what key I am sending in I should be able to tell which Bundle to look into for the key without looping through all my Bundles. So to say if I get the `Locale` for `fr_FR` and the `key` `PUSH_NOTIFICATION_REMINDER`, then I would know that I have to lookup for the text in `NotificationTexts_fr_FR.properties` without having to loop through all the resources as I am doing. So is it even possible to do it like this or do I have to loop through all my resources as I am doing now, and if loading resources for all Locales is possible how would I eventually need to handle property naming clashes so I do not get the wrong language property?

Comment: Why do you need to "load all ResourceBundles" though?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Because you can have your device set to a different language and in that case, you would want to receive the texts in that language, if not otherwise specified.

Comment: Yeah, but can't you do that by checking the Locale at runtime and getting the current locale  and then getting ResourceBundles for that locale? What am asking is why do you need to load all ResourceBundles at once? Or maybe I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am working currently on a solution which looks like this:

```
public class MyResourceBundle {

    private Map<Locale, Map<String, String>> localeResources;


    public MyResourceBundle() {
        localeResources = new HashMap<>();
        for (LocaleConfig config : LocaleConfig.values()) {
            Map<String, String> resources = new HashMap<>();

            ResourceBundle systemTexts = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SystemTexts", config.getLocale());
            ResourceBundle translationTexts = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TranslationTexts", config.getLocale());

            Enumeration systemKeys = systemTexts.getKeys();

            while (systemKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) systemKeys.nextElement();
                resources.put(key, systemTexts.getString(key));
            }

            Enumeration translationKeys = translationTexts.getKeys();
            while (translationKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) translationKeys.nextElement();
                resources.put(key, translationTexts.getString(key));
            }

            localeResources.put(config.getLocale(), resources);
        }

    }

    public String getText(Locale locale, String key) {
        String text = null;

        text = localeResources.get(locale).get(key);

        if (text == null) {
            String errorMessage = "Key: " + key + " does not exist for locale " + locale.toString();
            throw new MissingResourceException(errorMessage, this.getClass().getName(), key);
        }

        return text;
    }

}
```

LocaleConfig.java :

```
public enum LocaleConfig {

    DANISH("da", "DK"),
    ENGLISH("en", "GB")
    ;

    private String language;
    private String country;

    LocaleConfig(String language, String country) {
        this.language = language;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return new Locale(language, country);
    }
}
```

SystemTexts_da_DK.properties:

```
PERSON_1=Hans Hansen
PERSON_2=Anders Andersen
PERSON_3=Ib Ibsen

REMINDER_MESSAGE=Husk at teste...
```

SystemTexts_en_GB.properties:

```
PERSON_1=Frank Testerson
PERSON_2=Julie Testerson
PERSON_3=Test Testerson

REMINDER_MESSAGE=Remember to test...
```

TranslationTexts_da_DK.properties:

```
NOTE_NEW=Ny
NOTE_SEEN=Set
```

TranslationTexts_en_GB.properties:

```
NOTE_NEW=New
NOTE_SEEN=Seen
```

Now I can just call:

```
public class MyResourceBundleExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("da", "DK");

        MyResourceBundle myResourceBundle = new MyResourceBundle();

        System.out.println(myResourceBundle.getText(locale, "PERSON_3"));
    }

}
```

Initial tests on this solution show that this would work fine, but if anyone has a better solution or a more smooth way of doing this I am all ears :).